# How the JSON.parse() inside the static method is accessing class properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript and I was learning about "classes" and "static methods" in JavaScript. While learning, I came across a line of code, which I am unable to understand. Below is my whole code.

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  static parse(str) {
    const radius = JSON.parse().radius;
  }
}

const circle = Circle.parse('{"radius": 1}');
console.log(circle);
```

As you can see, inside my "static parse" method, the tutor who is teaching me is accessing the "radius" property from `Json.parse()`.

When I removed the ".radius" after the `JSON.parse()`, my code is still working.

Can you please tell me how `JSON.parse()` object is able to access my "radius" property and what is the purpose of writing this ".radius" if the code is still working without writing this?

Comment: `JSON.parse` doesn't work there, because an argument is required, but none are passed

Comment: I think you mean to have `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: yes, @awarrier99. I forgot to pass the parameter? Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @HimanshuVerma no problem, I just added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is not accessing your `radius` property. What `JSON.parse` does is take in a string representing data in the [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) format, and parse out the data as a JavaScript object. In this case, you're passing in the string `'{"radius": 1}'`, so when the library parses this string, it results in the object `{radius: 1}`. Then, you can access the `radius` property of this **resulting** object, **not** the `radius` property of the Circle class. Also, your `Circle.parse` method doesn't return anything. You probably want to do something like this:

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  static parse(str) {
    const radius = JSON.parse(str).radius;
    return new Circle(radius);
  }
}

const circle = Circle.parse('{"radius": 1}');
console.log(circle);
```

This parses the `radius` property from the string that you pass in, creates an instance of a Circle class with that `radius`, and returns it.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Thank you so much @awarrier99. My doubt is cleared now. Thanks Again!!